# Login in Java shows all users and all usertypes

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

i have a problem, currently my database looked like this:

> ID Username UserType
>
> 1  Nies     Administrator 2  Trinity  Member

When i login with Username: Nies

The program respond, but it gave me the dialog box where both Username are displayed.
I want only when i login with Username: Nies, the program also gave me the dialog box where only that Username will be displayed..

How do i fix that?

Here is the code that display a username and dialog box:

```
private void GetUsername(Connection conn, Statement state, ResultSet result)
    {
        try
        {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Database";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            state = conn.createStatement();

            String query = "select * from Member";

            result = state.executeQuery(query);

            while(result.next())
            {
                user = result.getString("Username");
                userType = result.getString("UserType");

                _userInformation.setUser(user);
                _userInformation.setUserType(userType);

                _sound.PlaySound(1);
                _infoBox.ShowMessageBox("Welcome! " + _userInformation.getUser() + " - " + _userInformation.getUserType() + " ", "Welcome" , 1);
            }
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            _sound.PlaySound(2);

            _infoBox.ShowMessageBox(e.getMessage(), "Error", 2);

            _reminder = new Reminder(1);

            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Program will be closed due to error", "Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

_infoBox.ShowMessageBox is the instance ShowMessageBox function inside InfoBox class where that function store JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if condition for that check.

```
If( user.equals("Nies Administrator") &&
                userType.equals("Trinity Member")){

 _sound.PlaySound(1);
 _infoBox.ShowMessageBox("Welcome! " + _userInformation.getUser() 
           + " - " + _userInformation.getUserType() + " ", "Welcome" , 1);

}else{

 // tell something to user
}
```

If you want to compare without case check use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm)

Comment: thanks for that. But, how about when i add another user to the database and login it immediately? I don't want to go back to the code and type if condition again like you wrote at the above. I want it automatically

Comment: Google "jdbc checking user login".